# How to persistently set an Environmental Variable using a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I tried this code in a notepad and save it as path.bat When I double click on the batch file, it won't set the Variable... Can anyone show me the error with my code or provide me the best solution?

```
@echo off
title This is your first batch script!
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Users\Core i3\Desktop\New folder (2)\jdk1.7.0_71"
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
exit
```

Comment: From the `setx` documentation (`setx /?`) there seem to be two things wrong: (1) `setx` uses `/` as the option indicator, not `-`, though it's possible that `-` is an undocumented alternative; (2) the `/m` parameter comes at the end of the run string, not the beginning.

Comment: can you give me the exact code with my path?

Comment: I'd have thought you could work that out. I could tell you what I _think_ the code would be, but without your set-up I couldn't test it, whereas you can. Why don't you try what the command seems to need? If that doesn't work then update your question to ask what is now wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your answer should be more like:

`setx /k <Path> <%yourpathhere%> <value to set>;`

It seems to me that you're missing the value to set in the second `setx` line.

[More information on "Setx"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: Can you give me the full code? by implementing my path as I mentioned above??? That would be really great...